# Show more link for Tabular Data

Tags: javascript, html

I have table with dynamic number of rows, lets say about 25.
Now onload of page I want to show just 10 of them and hide 15, on click of a **Show More** link I want to show all 25 rows.

Any help will be great on this
Thanks ,

Comment: Please give us an example of how you are populating this dynamic table.

Comment: welcome to stacoverflow .. before asking a question Please read http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Im am using 'velocity variable'  to create this dynamic table.
for example 
<table>
<tr><th>Data Name</th></tr>
#for($data: $dataList)
<tr><td>$data</td></tr>
#end
</table>

Answer (score 0):

Set all your rows to be `display:none` using css like

```
<tr class="your_class" style="display:none"></tr>
```

Use jquery page ready event like this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".your_class").slice(0, 9).each(function(index){
      $(this).css("display:block");
    });
 });
</script>
```

This will show the first 10 rows and all the others will remain hidden. Once the button is clicked, write event listener to that button like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonId").click(function(){
            $(".your_class").slice(10, 14).each(function(index){
              $(this).css("display:block");
            });
         });
});
```

Hope this will help..